# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "rtd" of relation "classroom_itembatch" already exists Keeps on coming evrytime

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a project with my team and whenever we update our app "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "rtd" of relation "classroom_itembatch" already exists" errors keeps on coming and it with throw same error on every table in data base untill all the database are recreated and remigrated. I don't know why this error keeps on coming everytime and the only sollution I have to this is to drop my database using postgress which is the worst sollution I think. Please help me to resolve this error.